# Woocommerce Show PDF attachment in Downloads tab as link

Tags: wordpress, pdf, woocommerce

I am trying to show a pdf in my downloads tab so that when someone is looking at my product they can open the pdf in a new window. I uploaded the pdf to the product via the media button. My callback looks like this and $attachments seems empty ideas?:

```
function woo_new_product_tab_content_downloads() {
global $woocommerce, $product, $post;    
$product_id = $post->ID;
echo $product_id; 
$product = new WC_Product( $product_id );
print_r($product);
// The new tab content
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $product_id,
    'post_mime_type' => array( 'application/pdf')
    );

   $attachments = get_posts( $args );
   //print_r($attachments);
  if ( $attachments ) {

    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {

       echo '<p><a href="';
       echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID );
       echo '">';
       echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, '', true );
       echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
       echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );
       echo '</a>';
       echo '</p>';
      } 
 }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks correct and should work. Sorry for a stupid question, but have you attached the PDF to the same product that you are viewing?

Comment: indeed I have as it is showing when I look into the uploaded attachments for the product.  $attachments = get_posts( $args ); seems empty when I print it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as an answer to myself be sure to attach the correct filetype

Comment: Could you be more specific about what steps you took to solve your problem? This might help people facing the same problem in the future.

Comment: My code was correct from the get go I had mistakenly uploaded a png insteadd of a pdf to the post.